# Clear input target

Tags: reactjs, database, button, input, onchange

I'm using an input to fetch data in  my database, but I'd like the input to be cleared after data is submitted.

```
        <input placeholder='Title' onChange={(event) => {setTitle(event.target.value);}}/> 
        <button onClick={writeTitleToDatabase}>Update Title</button>
```

I tried to use setTitle('') but it doesn't work properlly. The variable title is set to null but input field still filled.

```
const writeTitleToDatabase = () => {
    update(ref(database, 'id/' + fetchIdInfo),{      
      title          
    })
      setTitle('');
};
```

Comment: Hi @ppm.eth, looks like value attribute is missing for input tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add missing **value** attribute in the input tag

```
 <input placeholder='Title' value={title} onChange={(event) => {setTitle(event.target.value);}}/> 
    <button onClick={writeTitleToDatabase}>Update Title</button>
```